# EXECUTE statement is always called in stored procedure regardless of condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that prints out the correct statements based on and `IF ELSE` statement in a stored procedure. However, when I run it with the `EXECUTE` statement that I want to be called when the condition is true it seems to call the `EXECUTE` statement regardless of whether or not the `IF` condition is true or not. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
WHILE @count > 0
BEGIN
    SET @userID = (SELECT userId
                   FROM #roleMembers
                   WHERE @count = User_Key);

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT p.UserID
                   FROM #Supervisors AS s
                   INNER JOIN table_vw AS p ON p.ID = s.SupervisorID
                   WHERE p.ID = @userID)
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE dbo.myStoredProc;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Kept User: ' + @userID
    END

    SELECT @count = @count - 1;
END
```

For some reason when I have the query written like this the `EXECUTE` statement is always called regardless of the condition that is being evaluated in the `IF ELSE` statement.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that your `IF` statement can ever be false? For example, is it possible that @userID is always going to be null (say, because the @count variable never matches a user_key in your temporary table) and therefore the `IF NOT EXISTS` statement is always true? You might be able to help yourself by printing information (e.g. the values for @userID and @count) in the block that contains the procedure you're executing.

Comment: I've put print statements in the if and else and I do see it print when the if not exists condition is true which is when I would want to execute the SP. When I look at the messages tab in SSMS I see the correct print messages displayed. For some reason the execute statement seems to execute no matter what.